Two Different Pie Fillings
I want to bake a pie for my school club this upcoming Thursday, and while thinking of what kind to make had the idea to make a peaches and cream pie! The only thing is, when I looked it up, a lot of images showed a sort of cream pie with some peach mixed in, which isn't what I want to do.
My idea was to make a peach pie filling and a cream pie filling and try baking them into the same pie (I plan on making half of each recipe). Since the peach filling has actual fruit pieces in it, I'm planning on layering one on top of the other. Anyway, my questions are;

Will this even work?
Can the fillings be baked at the same time or do I need to do it separately?

Im very new to making Pies, so sorry if these seem obvious.

Anything is possible. But baking a layered pie and keeping the layers from sinking into each other as they bake is not generally a beginner technique. You would probably need to practice a lot to establish things like "which layer should be on top?" and "should I bake the bottom layer until it is set and then add the top?" as well as "should I cook the top layer in a pot or something to get it pretty much done before adding it to the bottom layer?" This is fiddly stuff.
I would suggest to either use an existing recipe for peaches and cream pie (perhaps including the word layer in your search will find one where someone has worked out all these issues and work you through the steps needed), or rein in your scope and just make a peach pie, perhaps with a lovely cream sauce or topping that you provide "on the side".
